# Popup over incoming-call screen on phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, popup, phonegap-plugins

I want a popup over incoming-call. I use phonegap 3.1 and I don't use native language.
I've detected ringing phone with [PhoneStateChangeListener](https://github.com/madeinstefano/PhoneStateChangeListener) and i want this:

[image]

A background image is also a good solution.

Can I to embed a native code??

Is it possible with phonegap plugin?

thank's.

Comment: PhoneStateChangeListener does not work with the recent version of PhoneGap.

Comment: i've followed https://github.com/madeinstefano/PhoneStateChangeListener/issues/3 and work fine for me.

Comment: hi Flavio i am new to phonegap. I need a clarification reagrding this phonestatechangelistener plugin.In my app index page i have started the phonestatechangelistener plugin.In PhoneStateChangeListener class ,if the state is ringing i have displayed the toast msg its working properly. But the problem is, in my index page  on back button click i have exit the app using navigator.app.exitApp(),after i came out of the app using back click. and making the call its not detecting the phonestate and not displaying the  toast msg. Thanks.

Comment: hi, I no longer have used this solution, I have used push notification sent ad hoc. However phonegap not working in background, js are stopped in background. My solution in this application: app ever active with background trasparent (I have changed view in native code), but this solution wasn't applicable in ios. Sorry for my english :-)